# What is the preferred method of accessing WWW::Mechanize responses?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

Are both of these versions OK or is one of them to prefer?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $content;

# 1
$mech->get( 'http://www.kernel.org' );
$content = $mech->content;
print $content;

# 2
my $res = $mech->get( 'http://www.kernel.org' );
$content = $res->content;
print $content;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [content()](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Econtent(...)) method is sometimes more convenient:

```
$mech->content(...)
```

Returns the content that the mech uses internally for the last page fetched. Ordinarily this is the same as $mech->response()->content(), but this may differ for HTML documents if "update_html" is overloaded, and/or extra named arguments are passed to content():

```
$mech->content( format => 'text' )
```

Returns a text-only version of the page, with all HTML markup stripped. This feature requires HTML::TreeBuilder to be installed, or a fatal error will be thrown.

```
$mech->content( base_href => [$base_href|undef] )
```

Returns the HTML document, modified to contain a  mark-up in the header. $base_href is $mech->base() if not specified. This is handy to pass the HTML to e.g. HTML::Display.

Comment: $mech->content( format => 'text' ) doesn't work with my machine.
(HTML::TreeBuilder is installed)

Comment: Check your version, you need WWW::Mechanize 1.05_03 or higher (released in 2004)

Comment: OK it works, maybe I was trunk when I tried it. But was there recently a WWW::Mechanize-version where this feature didn't work with perl 5.10.0 or 5.10.1?

Answer (score 3):

They are both acceptable. The second one seems cleaner to me because it returns a proper [HTTP::Response](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Response) object which you can query and call methods on, and also means that if you make another [Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize) request, you'll still have access to the old HTTP response. With your first approach, each time you make a request, the `content` method will change to something new, which sounds error-prone.

Btw, for either method, you should check `$response->is_success` or `$mech->success` before accessing the content, as the request may have failed.

Comment: From the perldoc: standalone WWW::Mechanize instances have autocheck turned on. However, if WWW::Mechanize is subclassed, it's off.

Comment: Oh wow, the last time I used Mechanize, that option didn't exist. That was in 2008... now I feel old :(

Comment: I added autocheck because of how staggeringly common it was for people to come into the #perl IRC channel and complain that $mech->content was empty, because they'd not bothered to check $mech->success.  Now, the most common case is the default.

Answer (score 1):

$mech->content is specifically there so you can bypass having to get the result response.  The simpler it is, the better.